# How to loop over a Map and update the property in the existing model in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class `SocialAuth`, which holds some common properties of the `AuthModel` class. Now I want to dynamically update the instance of `AuthModel` based on the object of `SocialAuth` class.

I'm looping over the `.toJson()` of `SocialAuth` and trying to update the property of `_authModel` *(Instance of AuthModel)* dynamically.

**ERROR IS - The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'AuthModel'.**

**SocialAuth Class**

```
@JsonSerializable()
class SocialAuth {
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? photoURL;

  SocialAuth({
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.photoURL,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$SocialAuthToJson(this);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'SocialAuth{email: $email, firstName: $firstName, lastName: $lastName, photoURL: $photoURL}';
  }
}
```

In my widget class, I'm calling a function `updateAuthModel()` which resides in my provider class like below:

```
 // Called from StateFull Widget class
  void _invokeGoogleAuth() async {
    var user = await SocialAuthService().getGoogleAuthData();
    _notifier.updateAuthModel(user!.toJson());
  }
```

```
// Provider class
...
void updateAuthModel(Map<String, dynamic> user) {
  user.forEach((key, value) {
   _authModel['$key'] = value; // IDE Error - The operator '[]=' isn't defined for the type 'AuthModel'.
  });
}
...
```

**AuthModel**

```
import 'package:aphrodite_v2/data/enums/enums.dart';

class AuthModel {
  String? firstName;
  String? lastName;
  String? mobile;
  String? email;
  String? dob;
  String? otp;
  String? pin;
  AuthStatus status;

  AuthModel({
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.mobile,
    this.dob,
    this.email,
    this.status = AuthStatus.UNDEFINED,
    this.otp,
    this.pin,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'mobile': mobile,
      'dob': dob,
      'email': email,
      'status': status,
      'otp': otp,
      'pin': pin,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error, as the operator `[]=` isn't defined for the type `AuthModel` as the `AuthModel` class has not defined the `[]` operator.

You will need to define the operator `[]` in the `AuthModel` class,

```dart
void operator []=(String key, dynamic value) {
// Do this for each field in your class
if (key == 'firstName') firstName = value;
if (key == 'lastName') lastName = value;
...
}
```

If you want your class to behave like a `Map` object you can also mixin the `MapMixin`.

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

class AuthModel with MapMixin {
  @override
  operator [](Object? key) {
    // TODO: implement []
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  void operator []=(key, value) {
    // TODO: implement []=
  }

  @override
  void clear() {
    // TODO: implement clear
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement keys
  Iterable get keys => throw UnimplementedError();

  @override
  remove(Object? key) {
    // TODO: implement remove
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

[Docs for MapMixin class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.3/dart-collection/MapMixin-class.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you add some example or some more detail?

Comment: Update the answer with a simple example of what you can do.

Comment: @YashwardhanPauranik Added an alternative option as well as the docs link, for info on Maps in dart